# Java 8 -Flatten Map with Lists

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a structure such as Map`<String,List<Map<String,Object>>`. I want to apply a function to the map as follows. The method takes a key and uses a 
 Map`<String,Object>` of the list.  Each key has several Map`<String,Object>` in the list. How can I apply the process method to the map's key for each value of Map`<String,Object>`? I was able to use to forEach loops(see below) but I have a feeling this is not the best way to solve the problem in a functional way.

```
TypeProcessor p=new TypeProcessor.instance();

//Apply this function to the key and each map from the list
// The collect the Result returned in a list.
Result process(String key, Map<String,Object> dataPoints);
```

```
List<Result> list = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach(key,value) -> {
  value.forEach(innerVal -> {
    Result r=p.process(key,innerVal);
    list.add(r):
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this **compile**? I don't get why you can write **types** at regular method calls like`p.process(...)`. And also it seems there is a semicolon missing at the end of `new ArrayList<>()`. And also the `value.forEach(` opens a bracket `(` that is never closed at `(innverVal`. And after the `->` there should be enclosing `{ ... }` curly brackets as you're executing more than one statement.

Comment: I simply typed part of the code that works.  I am just showing the procedure that works, not that the code here is exactly as the one in the application,that I've got working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems from your code that you want to apply `process` for the entire `Map`, so you could do it like this:

```
 List<Result> l = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(value -> process(e.getKey(), value)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming `map` contains `key`, you don't need any `foreach`. Just obtain the value from the outer `map`, stream it, map to your new object and collect to a `List`:

```
List<Result> list = 
    map.get(key)
       .stream()
       .map(v -> p.process(key,v))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```